# Printing from HP printer in Excel with 2 trays

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, network-printer, paper-tray

I am working in Excel 2013 and have an HP Officejet Pro X476dw printer. The issue that I am having is that when I select multiple worksheets to print, the first page is always printing from tray 1 and the remaining from tray 2.

I have gone into my printer preferences and specified tray 1 in the 'printing shortcuts' tab. I have also gone into the 'Paper/Quality' tab and selected settings for 'Special Pages'. In there, I have 2 items I can select - 'Covers' and 'Print pages on different paper'. For each one, I have specified the paper source as tray 1 and added it to the list at the bottom. However the printer will still print everything from page 2 onwards from tray 2.

Am I missing any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Excel uses different printer settings for each worksheet, even within the same workbook. For each worksheet, go to Page Layout and click the arrow in the bottom right corner of Page Setup. Then click the Options button and check the settings there

Is this only happening with Excel?

Comment: Yes this only happens in Excel. Other Microsoft and non Microsoft products seem to print consistently. Thanks for your suggestion, I will give that a go. Would be strange if there wasn't a way to set a default tray for all worksheets in a project.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to set them all at once. Each worksheet gets the current settings for the current printer. If you change settings for one worksheet and then add another, that one will get the original settings.